# Code does not run on second attempt

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The program runs from a button and loads the XMLHTTP GET request.

The first time the button is clicked, it works.

When I click it after the first time, nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oXMLHTTP
    Dim oStream

    oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

    oXMLHTTP.Open("GET", "http://test.com/ricky.php", False)
    oXMLHTTP.Send()

End Sub
```

Comment: vb.net <> vba.  I have removed that tag.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get it. The code should execute the oXMLHTTP everytime the button is clicked. Not just 1 time :(

Comment: Did you close oXMLHTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to close *oXMLHTTP* like so:

```
oXMLHTTP.Close()
```

So the full method would be:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oXMLHTTP
    Dim oStream

    oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

    oXMLHTTP.Open("GET", "http://test.com/ricky.php", False)
    oXMLHTTP.Send()
    oXMLHTTP.Close()
End Sub
```